# Probability distributions on the unit disk

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Are there any interesting probability distributions on the unit disk ${x \in \mathbb{C} : \vert x\vert \le 1}$ (or the equivalent on $\mathbb{R}^2$)? Interesting qualities include:

- Is named, or has at least been studied
- Has a PDF, CDF, or characteristic function that can be expressed simply, or at least analytically.
- Has one of the circular distributions (von Mises, wrapped whatever) as a marginal or conditional distribution

The only such distribution I have seen mentioned on this site is the uniform distribution on the disk.

Any distribution on the plane can be transformed onto the disk, but I haven't come across one that results in a nice or useful form after the transformation.

Comment: Bivariate Normal distribution springs to mind.

Comment: @tomi The bivariate normal is not supported on the unit disk.